# Spinnaker github webhook does not trigger pipeline

Tags: spinnaker

I have followed the [guide for github pipeline triggers via webhooks](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/triggers/github/) and while I can verify that the webhook was sent successfully with the exact filepath artifact, my pipeline is not triggered.

I have verified the artifact expected is sent and the response is 200 from github with body:

```
{"eventId":"5a05b1b0-ac9f-4222-bdeb-caa1a7f4b216","eventProcessed":true}
```

I have checked the `echo` log and there doesn't seem to be anything but startup information.  It must not be logging webhooks and responses, or else I figured I would see the ^^`eventId` I received on the github side.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/3227e24a125ac5a928ab7e4f1dd2a687) with this information including the payload.

Below is an image of the pipeline config - at this time I'm just trying to trigger it and get a slack notification, but nothing is triggered:

[image: spinnaker-ui]

What am I missing here?  How can I debug further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error thanks to Pere on the spinnaker slack channel.

I have the spinnaker trigger watching `master` (which is what I want for production), and I was commit/pushing test files to `develop`.  So while the webhook is configured to push for any case, it is filtering it on the spinnaker side.  Changing the trigger to watch `develop` worked.

As a side note, neither successful nor unsuccessful triggers showed in the `echo` log.